# Use strtok read csv file

Tags: c, csv, strtok

I am trying to use strtok in C to read csv file, and store the contents into array of struct Game.
My code is shown below:

```
  FILE *fp;
  int i = 0;
  if((fp=fopen("Games.csv","r"))==NULL)
    {
      printf("Can't open file.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  rewind(fp);
  char buff[1024]; 
  fgets(buff,1024,fp);
  char* delimiter = ",";

  while(fgets(buff, 1024, (FILE*)fp)!=NULL && i<5){

    Game[i].ProductID= strtok(buff, ",");   


    Game[i].ProductName = strtok(NULL, delimiter);

        Game[i].Publisher = strtok(NULL, delimiter);

    Game[i].Genre = strtok(NULL, delimiter);

    Game[i].Taxable = atoi(strtok(NULL, delimiter));

    Game[i].price = strtok(NULL, delimiter);

    Game[i].Quantity  = atoi(strtok(NULL, delimiter));


       printf("%s\n", Game[i].ProductID);

    i++;
   }


    i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
       printf("%s", Game[i].ProductID);
    }
```

The output is shown below:

```
DS_25ROGVOIRY
DS_25MMD4N2BL
DS_258KADVNLH
DS_25UR7M375D
DS_25FP45CJFZ
DS_25AN1EA3PV,Blitz I: The League,Midway Games,Sports,0,$103.03 ,2
DS_25AN1EA3PV,Blitz I: The League,Midway Games,Sports,0,$103.03 ,2
DS_25AN1EA3PV,Blitz I: The League,Midway Games,Sports,0,$103.03 ,2
DS_25AN1EA3PV,Blitz I: The League,Midway Games,Sports,0,$103.03 ,2
DS_25AN1EA3PV,Blitz I: The League,Midway Games,Sports,0,$103.03 ,2
```

The first five lines (in the while loop) are correct. However, the last five lines( outside of while loop) are wrong, it print the whole line content.

I am so confused about it. When the array is changed and how to still print the correct answer after while loop.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, strtok can give you unexpected behavior parsing csvs.   ie  "a,b,,c,d" will parse as 4 values instead of 5.

Comment: CSV can have embedded commas in fields. For example, `zero,"one,two",three` is three fields. `strtok()` isn't going to be able to deal with that.

Answer (score 4):

First, a primer on how `strtok()` works. The function will give you back a pointer to somewhere in the *original* string, said string having been modified to make it look like you only have a single token <sup>(a)</sup>.

For example, the first `strtok` of `"A,B,C"` would turn it into `"A\0B,C"` and give you back the address of the `A` character. Using it at that point would then give you `"A"`.

Similarly, the second call would turn it into `"A\0B\0C"` and give you back the address of the `B` character.

The fact that it's giving you pointers into the original string is paramount here because that original string is located in `buff`.

And, you're actually *overwriting* `buff` every time you read a line from the file. So, for all those five lines, `Game[i].ProductID` will simply be the address of the first character of `buff`. After you have processed the fifth line, the line:

```
while (fgets(buff, 1024, fp) != NULL && i < 5)
```

will first read in the sixth line *before* exiting the loop.

This is why the final lines you see are actually *not* the same as any of the first five. You're printing out all the C strings for `ProductID`, at the (identical) addresses of `buff`, so you only see the sixth one, and you see the *full* line because you didn't tokenise that one after reading it in.

What you need to do is to make a *copy* of the tokens before overwriting the line. That can be done with something like (it's a little complex but correctly handles the case where `strtok` returns NULL):

```
if ((Game[i].ProductID = strtok(buff, ",")) != NULL)
    Game[i].ProductID = strdup(Game[i].ProductID);
```

remembering that you should `free` those memory allocations at some point.

In the *incredibly* unlikely event your environment doesn't have a `strdup` (it's POSIX rather than ISO), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c/252802#252802).

---

And, just as an aside, most CSV implementations allow for embedded commas such as by enclosing them in quotes or escaping them (the latter is rare but I *have* seen them):

```
name,"diablo, pax",awesome
name,diablo\, pax,awesome
```

Both of those may be expected to be three fields, `name`, `diablo, pax` and `awesome`.

Simplified processing with `strtok` will not allow for such complexities but, assuming your fields do not contain embedded commas, it may be okay. If your input *is* more complex, you may be better off using a third-party CSV library (with a suitable licence of course).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> For the language lawyers among us, this is covered in the ISO C standard, `C11 7.24.5.8 The strtok function, /3 and /4` (my bold):

> 3/ The first call in the sequence searches the string pointed to by `s1` for the first character that is *not* contained in the current separator string pointed to by `s2`. If no such character is found, then there are no tokens in the string pointed to by `s1` and the `strtok` function returns a null pointer. If such a character is found, ***it is the start of the first token***.
>
> 4/ The `strtok` function then searches from there for a character that *is* contained in the current separator string. If no such character is found, the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to by `s1`, and subsequent searches for a token will return a null pointer. If such a character is found, ***it is overwritten by a null character, which terminates the current token.*** The strtok function saves a pointer to the following character, from which the next search for a token will start.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is really helpful for me.